# Web service PHP code with cUrl into laravel

Tags: php, web-services, laravel, curl

I have a simple web service written in php but since I have to implement it to laravel framework, I'm now lost. I've tried to put the code to the controller or even the blade.php file but neither works. Any tips on how to convert this? Here is my code:

```
$query = "SELECT distinct gcm_registration_id from users";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$results = array();

while($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    $registrationIds[] = $line['gcm_registration_id'];
}
$msg = array
(
    'message'   => 'This is a test',
    'title'     => 'This is a title. title',
    'subtitle'  => 'This is a subtitle. subtitle',
    'tickerText'    => 'Ticker text here...Ticker text here...Ticker text here',
    'vibrate'   => 1,
    'sound'     => 1,
    'largeIcon' => 'large_icon',
    'smallIcon' => 'small_icon'
);
$fields = array
(
    'registration_ids'  => $registrationIds,
    'data'          => $msg
);

$headers = array
(
    'Authorization: key=' . 'my-authorization-key',
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send' );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
$result = curl_exec($ch );
curl_close( $ch );
```

It is fired when a button is clicked. The code is this:

```
$(document).on("click", "#stop_nomination", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var election_id = $(this).data('id');
    $this = $(this);

    if(window.confirm("Are you sure you want to end nomination?")) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "{{ URL::route('json/stopNomination') }}",
            data: { election_id: election_id }, //PASS DATA 
            success: function(data){ // RECEIVE DATA
                alert(data.msg);
                if(data.error != 1) {
                    $("#stop_nomination").css("display", "none");
                    $("#start_nomination").css("display", "block");
                    $("#div-nomination").css("display", "none");
                    $("#div-election").css("display", "block");
                    $("#text-nomination").html("Completed");
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I understand that it's calling the function on the controller which basically makes a query and update some information on the database. I tried inserting my code but it won't work.

**Update:**
So far, I've found a way to execute the code. What I did is I put the code on a php file and then put the url under `$.ajax`. But since the url on `$.ajax` doesn't accept two url's at the same time, what I wanted is to put the php url file into the controller function. Can someone tell me how to fire a php url file inside a controller function?

Comment: When is this supposed to fire?

Comment: @Anderscc It should be fired when a button is clicked.

Comment: You could write a class with the method implementing the cURL logic then call that method inside the controller's method which is called when the button is clicked.